# High CPU utilization on server

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

> Server Configuration:

- Virtual Dedicated
- Windows Server 2008, Xeon Processor 1.6GHZ, 4GB RAM
- MS SQL Server R2 Express
- IIS 7.0
- .NET Framework 4.0

> Problem:

- Very slow response of the website due to HIGH CPU usage.
- Sometimes Site works fine, but suddenly it goes slow down and
  static HTML pages also not responding quickly.
- Whenever we restart the server or SQL SERVER service, site works
  fine for while, but after sometime site performance decreased and
  site goes slow down.

> We Tried Solution:

- Optimized all Stored Procedure, Remove all unwanted TEMP tables from Stored Procedures.
- Removed all unwanted code, comments. Unused links, file references from the source code.
- There is antivirus on the server, we scanned whole server but no virus found.
- We stop unwanted services in the server.
- We remove unnecessary application from the server too.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9615742/sql-server-2008-r2-high-cpu-usage?rq=1

Comment: @pleinolijf thanx for your replay,but i have already tried the same,but i dont get any result for that query,that means the problem is not regarding that issue

Comment: You've not got much memory and that CPU is quite slow too.

Comment: So High CPU usage - What process is doing it? What's the typical usage you expect in normal operations? You're approaching this as  if it were a fault - how have you eliminated the possibility that it's simply a capacity issue? As its a virtual machine, how many cores are allocated to it? How much contention for host resources is there?

Answer (score 0):

Start clearing the process cache.

Analyze page replacement statistics.

Remove disk level compression if any.

Comment: Can you expand on this a little ?